# How to drop a template database from PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, drop, database-template

```
postgres=# DROP DATABASE template_postgis;
ERROR:  cannot drop a template database
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html makes it seem like if I set `template_postgis.datistemplate = false`, I'll be able to drop it, but I don't know how to set that.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
postgres=# UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate='false' WHERE datname='template_postgis';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# DROP DATABASE template_postgis;
DROP DATABASE
postgres=#
```

Comment: I looked in the script I used that created the template. There was the line `psql -d postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate='true' WHERE datname='template_postgis';"`.

Comment: This causes further problems. I made an upgrade from 9.1 -> 9.2 on ubuntu. This created template1 implicitly. I then executed your command and it seems to work. However, now I installed phpPgAdmin and I cannot login, it says : 'FATAL:  database "template1" does not exist'

Comment: To re-create template1:
`create database template1 template template0;`
`UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate='true' WHERE datname='template1';`
See also:  http://pgsql.inb4.se/2009/april/rebuild-template1.html

Answer (score 48):

You can use the alter database command. Much simpler and safer than upsetting metadata.

```
postgres=# create database tempDB is_template true;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# drop database tempDB;
ERROR:  cannot drop a template database
postgres=# alter database tempDB is_template false;
ALTER DATABASE
postgres=# drop database tempDB;
DROP DATABASE
postgres=#
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html)

Comment: This solution works and is far less complicated than the selected solution.

Comment: @amoe Great spot. Edited to add documentation link

Comment: Thank god you exist man. All the other solutions didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: This works, but make sure to add single quotes around `'false'` *POSTGRES v10*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you can drop `template0` and `template1` databases which PostgreSQL has by default with the SQLs below:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE template0 IS_TEMPLATE FALSE;
DROP DATABASE template0;
```

```sql
ALTER DATABASE template1 IS_TEMPLATE FALSE;
DROP DATABASE template1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update pg_database set datistemplate=false where datname='template0';
update pg_database set datistemplate=false where datname='template1';

....

Creating script to analyze new cluster                      ok
Creating script to delete old cluster                       ok
Checking for hash indexes                                   ok

Upgrade Complete
----------------
```