# How to change the template database collection coding

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I want build new postgreSQL database by:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb
WITH OWNER = postgres
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

and the error is:

> ERROR:  new collation (zh_CN.UTF-8) is incompatible with the collation of the template    database (en_US.UTF8)
>   HINT:  Use the same collation as in the template database, or use template0 as template.

How to change the template database collection?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) documentation:

> Another common reason for copying template0 instead of template1 is
>   that new encoding and locale settings can be specified when copying
>   template0, whereas a copy of template1 must use the same settings it
>   does. This is because template1 might contain encoding-specific or
>   locale-specific data, while template0 is known not to.

You can use only `template0` to create new database with different encoding and locale:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb
WITH OWNER = postgres
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
   TEMPLATE template0;
```

This will work, however it means that any changes you made to `template1` won't be applied to newly created database.

To change encoding and collation of `template1` you have to first delete `template1` and then create new template `template1` from `template0`. How to drop template database is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388786/how-does-one-drop-a-template-database-from-postgresql). Then you can create new database `template1` with chosen encoding/collation and mark it as a template by setting `datistemplate=true` ([example](http://colinnewell.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/creating-a-new-postgres-template-database/)):

```
update pg_database set datistemplate=true  where datname='template1';
```

Comment: What's special about `template0`?  I can `set datistemplate=false` and drop it as well, so if I recreated it how would I configure it to allow creating a database with different encoding and locale from it?

Comment: The docs even say "template1 and template0 do not have any special status beyond the fact that the name template1 is the default source database name for CREATE DATABASE."  But there must be some flag or data in `template0` that cause pg to allow different encoding and locale...

Answer (score 38):

Tomas answer is correct, but it is missing an important detail (`LC_CTYPE`). Here is the full sequence for recreating `template1` with the correct locale:

```
ALTER database template1 is_template=false;

DROP database template1;

CREATE DATABASE template1
WITH OWNER = postgres
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'
   LC_CTYPE = 'zh_CN.UTF-8'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
   TEMPLATE template0;

ALTER database template1 is_template=true;
```

then you can create new databases.

Comment: This is the **most correct and complete answer** for `How to change the template database?`