# Failing to create database in Postgres 9.3 with Norwegian (Bokmål) locale

Tags: postgresql, localization, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to create a database using this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE workgroup WITH TEMPLATE = template0 
ENCODING = 'UTF8' 
LC_COLLATE = 'Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252' 
LC_CTYPE = 'Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252';
```

But it fails with this error:

```
"ERROR:  invalid locale name: "Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252"

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid locale name: "Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252" SQL state: 42809"
```

I added Norwegian (Bokmål) keyboard on Windows 7, and also failed with standard 'a' (Bokmal) and without the space.

Creating the DB with this locale:

```
LC_COLLATE='Estonian_Estonia.1257' 
LC_CTYPE='Estonian_Estonia.1257'
```

works fine.

I've installed Windows 9.3 Postgres with the Norwegian Bokmal locale, but then queried the database for the locales using the SQL commands:

```
show LC_COLLATE;
show LC_CTYPE;

SELECT *
FROM   pg_settings
WHERE  name ~~ 'lc%';
```

It returns empty data for LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE.

What should be the LC* values for the Norwegian (Bokmål) locale?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem trying a query that worked on windows and didn't work on linux:

```
CREATE DATABASE testingDB
WITH OWNER = postgres
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'
   LC_CTYPE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

When I changed

```
'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'
```

to

```
'pt_BR.UTF8'
```

I then got another problem:

> new collation (pt_BR.UTF8) is incompatible with the collation of the
>   template database (en_US.UTF-8)

which is self explained, my system and database uses another locale, so I [fixed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870775/how-to-change-the-template-database-collection-coding-on-postgresql#18873193).

you can find more about your postgres version collation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/collation.html)

I believe this should fix your issue:

```
CREATE DATABASE workgroup WITH TEMPLATE = template0 
ENCODING = 'UTF8' 
LC_COLLATE = 'nb_NO.UTF8' 
LC_CTYPE = 'nb_NO.UTF8';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing `\dOs+` in psql, it will show a list of available locales.

Comment: Command does not show any locales, workgroup=# \dOs+
              List of collations
 Schema | Name | Collate | Ctype | Description
--------+------+---------+-------+-------------
(0 rows)