# Hide template database in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In order to change the collation of PostgreSQL's database template, I dropped `template1` and recreated it with the 'correct' collation. I therefore got my inspiration from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870775/how-to-change-the-template-database-collection-coding-on-postgresql).

All fine now, but now that newly database template `template1` is listed in the available databases in the tree view. 
I compared database `pg_database` for two servers (one listing the database `template1`, one not), but the values of the parameters for database `template1` are the same.

I would like to hide this database from in the tree view.
Anyone who can figure this out?

EDIT: [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/889287/hide-default-postgre-and-template-databases-from-end-users) did not bring me any further

*(PostgreSQL 9.6, pgAdmin 1.22)*

Comment: This Question might be better served in the [*DBA Stack Exchange*](https://dba.stackexchange.com) rather than *Stack Overflow*.

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin uses the [following condition](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin3/blob/794527d97e2e3b01399954f3b79c8e2585b908dd/pgadmin/schema/pgDatabase.cpp#L928) to show the database in the tree or not:

```
/* Condition used to show database */
if (settings->GetShowSystemObjects() || !database->GetSystemObject())
    (...)

/* Function called above */
bool pgDatabase::GetSystemObject() const
{
    if (server)
    {
        if (this->GetName() == wxT("template0")) return true;
        return (this->GetOid() <= server->GetLastSystemOID());
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unless you've marked "Show System Objects in the treeview" option, I guess that your template1's oid is greater than LastSystemOID (`pg_database.datlastsysoid`). In this case you have three options:

1. Rebuild your cluster with right collation;
2. Accept that;
3. or, assuming you weren't in production, play with
   `pg_database.datlastsysoid` and wait for side effects.

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin had an [issue](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/5875) where `template1` was shown even if the option was turned off to show system objects. This happened when you **migrated** your database before via `pg_upgrade`.

The image below shows the template database in the current pgAdmin version with the `Show system object` option **enabled**:

[image]

The issue was in the condition shown by [Michel Milezzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50672272/4300087). It is [not correct](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1867088.1601992521%40sss.pgh.pa.us) to determine that a database is a template by `oid <= lastSystemOid`. Because when you use `pg_upgrade`, the `oid` of the `template1` database is changed and the new value is higher than the `lastSystemOid` (i don't know if this is also a bug).

```
oid    datname    datlastsysoid  datacl
13394  template0  13394          {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
1      template1  13394          {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}

after using pg_upgrade:
13756  template0  13756          {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
16446  template1  13756          {postgres=CTc/postgres,=c/postgres}
 ^
```